# Enumerate list of MVC Model validation errors in code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

Within MVC 3, is there a mechanism that allows the enumeration of all validation errors before returning the resulting View?

For Example:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    //Enumerate validation errors
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

You can loop through the ModelStateValues collection

#### Sample

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    foreach (ModelState modelState in ModelState.Values) {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors) {
            // error.ErrorMessage contains the error message
        }
    }
}
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - ModelState.Value Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstate.value.aspx)